# Taylor series expansion of a challeging type of polynomial with two summation signs

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, polynomials, series-expansion, algebraic-manipulation

I have a few questions about series expansions of a particular and difficult type of polynomial written in terms of two summations signs.

**It should be remarked that I have also read Mathematica's documentation and previous posts on Mathematica stack exchange. However, those did not help me with the questions to be presented. Based on the great interest in series expansion in one or more variables, I believe these questions and their possible answers may be of great interest to those to subscribe to the Mathematica stack exchange.**

With that said, suppose that we have the following polynomial,

$$\sum _{j=0}^n \sum _{i=0}^j (K y+\sigma )^iy^{j-i} a_{i,j-i},$$

in which $n$ is the maximum degree of algebraic expression above.
Based on the above, I ask:

1. Is there another way to perform a Taylor series expansion of the expression above using Mathematica?

It is critical to recognize that I have tried to use Mathematica to obtain the Taylor series expansion of the expression above. Nevertheless, Mathematica does not return a result but rather the same command. That is,

```
Series[Sum[y^(j-i) a[i,j-i](K*y+b)^i,{j,0,n},{i,0,j}],{y,0,2}]
```

2. How may I determine the maximum order of the resultant expression from the series expansion?

Comment: The syntax for `Sum[]` is `Sum[..., {j, 0, n}, {i, 0, j}]`, but maybe that is a mis-edit? But since [one can easily copy and paste code](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) from Mathematica, maybe it isn't.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2. I have corrected it, as you may see above.

Comment: The "Sum" function in your expression can not evaluate with unknown "n". Further , the Taylor expansion of a polynomial around zero is the polynomial itself.

Comment: Hi @DanielHuber, I hope you are doing well. What do you mean by "The Sum function in your expression can not evaluate with unknown n"?, because I may compute derivatives with the expression outlined in my question. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: In "Sum[y^(j-i) a[i,j-i](K*y+b)^i,{j,0,n},{i,0,j}]" n is not know. That is why Sum does not evaluate.